# Detect auto reply emails programmatically

Tags: c#, .net

I have scenario where I would have to track the delivery of the emails I send programmatically and flag those recipients who have set either 'Out of Office" OR have the message delivery failed due to over-sized inbox OR if their email ID doesn't exist. Such instances usually send out automated replies. How can I track them? Does .NET (System.Net.Mail) offer any APIs to do it?

Comment: If you're talking about a generic solution for any common email protocol - no there isn't.

Comment: @RashmiKantShrivastwa The application is on Azure. Database Mail isnt supported yet.

Comment: @Neowizard The mails are usually sent to Active Directory users.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no set of checks for auto-responses that produce perfect behavior (detect all auto-replies with no false positives), but the following checks have worked well so far:

- header `Auto-Submitted` with value other than `no` (see [RFC
  3834](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834))
- headers `X-Autoreply` or `X-Autorespond` with any value
- header `Precedence` with value `auto_reply`

I don't yet have any advice for detecting message delivery failure notifications.

Comment: An "reply" without the "In-Reply-To" is also an auto-reply.

Comment: Here is a nice article for detecting auto response: https://arp242.net/autoreply.html